# como poner transparente header en modo desktop

Tags: jquery

Muy buenas!

estoy intentando poner el header en formato para moviles transparente he puesto el css correspondiente pero me comentan que sigue blanco porque jquery debe tener esa función.

Si alguien supiera decirme en que carpeta encontrar donde esta jquery para configurar la cabecera transparente en moviles se lo agradecería muchísimo

un cordial saludo!

Comment: Buenas, puedes poner el código para que podamos ver cual es el fallo o bien poder guiarnos para poder ayudarte? ya que así no entiendo bien que es lo que quieres hacer. Un saludo

Comment: @KeTeMeTo. Lo que necesito es poner el header transparente en version moviles (en formato desktop ya me funciona) pongo el css correspondiente para que se vea el header transparente en moviles pero a pesar de que la transparencia funciona me sigue saliendo blanco. Me comentan que sigue saliendo blanco seguramente porque manda jquery y deberia cambiarlo ahi . Necesitaría saber por norma general cual sería la carpeta de jquery que se configura la header para moviles. dejo link de la web . www.morama.com . muchas gracias por tu rápida respuesta

Comment: Ya entiendo lo que quieres hacer, edita la pregunta y pon por favor como pones transparente el modo desktop y así vemos cual es el problema de que en modo móvil no funcione

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el error es que el posicionamiento de la imagen es relativo, y el encabezado por mucho que lo pongas transparente no se pone encima de la imagen, para arreglas esto agrega esto a tu css y te debería funcionar

```
#apus-header-mobile{
    background-color: transparent !important;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias! de gran ayuda para mi. recibe un cordial saludo

Comment: @marmardigan nada para eso estamos!